# VB6 Handle error raising in error handler

Tags: error-handling, vb6

I have code like this, so when error is raised for the first time (c=1/0) then is going in error handle, after that it going in Again an if there is raised error than app is crashing, not going in error handler, any idea how to fix this?

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
   maxretry=3
   c=1/0
Again:
     c=a/b
ErrorHandler:
      if maxretry>0 then
          maxretry=maxretry-1
          goto Again

       end if
```

Comment: I think you need another `On Error` at `Again:`

Comment: In the above code, c will always = a/b at the end of the block, regardless of if c = 1/0 causes an exception or not...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd rather use `RESUME` than `GOTO` in the error handler section:

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
   maxretry=3
   c=1/0
Again:
     c=a/b
ErrorHandler:
      if maxretry>0 then
          maxretry=maxretry-1
          Resume Again

       end if
```

Using `RESUME` will, sort of, reset the internal error handler flag and giving you re-entrance in it (sort of).

`Resume Again` tells VB6 to resume execution of code (after error is processed) at line labelled `Again:`

You could also use `Resume Next` that tells VB6 to resume at the next instruction just after the one that causes the error.

If you want to retry your operation, you'll have to put another label and update your code that should most likely look like this:

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Max number of tries.
    maxretry = 3

Retry:
    c = 1 / 0

NoMoreTry:
    c = a / b

Exit Sub
' or Exit Function
' to avoid entering error handler because we don't need to

ErrorHandler:
    If (maxretry > 0) Then
        maxretry = maxretry - 1
        ' Try again, resume execution to "Retry" label.
        Resume Retry
    End If
    ' Tried 3 times, resume execution to "NoMoreTry" label.
    Resume NoMoreTry
```

Be aware, in this particular case, that if your b variable is equal to 0 you'd probably have an infinite loop, because as `c = a / b` will fail, then it goes to the error handler that will resume execution to NoMoreTry, then fail, ... and so on...

To avoid this, you can use `On Error Resume Next` right after NoMoreTry, or add more code in the error handler.